# Django with ajax render

Tags: python, ajax, django, forms, validation

I am pretty new to Django and I try to create my first application. However I faced a problem now.

I have a form (to add Alert - my mdoel) with Django validation and a div with list of all alerts. If I fill all fields correctly the alert is added and my div with alerts is refreshed using ajax. The problem is with form validation.

Without ajax I was sending bound form with errorLists for every field. I used Django form API. It was working ok but I can't refresh the errorlist if adding a form couldn't succeed.

I am getting either no render of form or render without context - all fields are blank. Of course they shouldn't be blank if I made a mistake in one field and It was working OK without ajax.

Bunch of code, First this is the view method I call:

```
def add_alert(request):
    report = __get_or_create_empty_Report(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AlertForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            alert_project = ""
            alert_name = ""
            alert_ticket = ""
            alert_date = ""
            alert_type = ""
            alert_comment = ""

            if form.cleaned_data.has_key('alert_project'):
                alert_project = form.cleaned_data['alert_project']
            if form.cleaned_data.has_key('alert_name'):
                alert_name = form.cleaned_data['alert_name']
            if form.cleaned_data.has_key('alert_ticket'):
                alert_ticket = form.cleaned_data['alert_ticket']
            if form.cleaned_data.has_key('alert_date'):
                alert_date = form.cleaned_data['alert_date']
            if form.cleaned_data.has_key('alert_type'):
                alert_type = form.cleaned_data['alert_type']
            if form.cleaned_data.has_key('alert_comment'):
                alert_comment = form.cleaned_data['alert_comment']

            alert = Alert()
            alert.alt_prj_id = get_object_or_404(Project, prj_id=alert_project)
            alert.alt_name = alert_name
            alert.alt_ticket = alert_ticket
            alert.alt_date = alert_date
            alert.alt_type = alert_type
            comment = Comment()
            comment.com_value = alert_comment
            comment.save()
            alert.alt_com_id = comment
            alert.alt_rep_id = report

            alert.save()
            alerts  = Alert.objects.filter(alt_rep_id=report.rep_id)
            return render(request, 'main/theform.html', {'form': form, 'alerts': alerts, 'error_message': "Alert has been added"})
    else:
        form = AlertForm()
        alerts  = Alert.objects.filter(alt_rep_id=report.rep_id)
        return render(request, 'main/theform.html', {'form': form, 'alerts': alerts})

    alerts  = Alert.objects.filter(alt_rep_id=report.rep_id)
    return render(request, 'main/theform.html', {'form': form, 'alerts': alerts, 'error_message': "Alert has NOT been added"})
```

Here's the form template:

```
    {% extends 'main/base.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <div id="alerts"> </div>
        {% for alert in alerts %}
            <p> {{ alert.alt_name }} </p>
        {% endfor %}


        <form class="col-md-12" action="{% url 'main:add_alert' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        {{ error_message }}


{% endblock %}
```

and simple script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //AJAX util
        $('.add-alert-form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $(this).attr("action"),
                data: $(this).serialize(),

                success: function (data) {
                    $("#alerts").load(" #alerts");
                }
            });
        });
   }
```

I think I am doing it completly wrong but I have no idea what's the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/
so your views would look like that:

```
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save()
            data = serializers.serialize('json', [obj,])
        else:
            data = json.dumps(dict([(k, [unicode(e) for e in v]) for k,v in form.errors.items()]))

        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```